# aes mapping ggplot2 consistency

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am learning ggplot2 and have the following sample example:

```
library(ggplot2)

# Aesthetic gets mapped correctly here
# don't mention `aes` in `geom_point`
ans2 <- ggplot(anscombe, aes(x = x2, y = y2))
ans2 <- ans2 + geom_point(colour = "blue", size = 5)
ans2

# Aesthetic does NOT get mapped correctly here
# explicitly mention `aes` in `geom_point`!
# this should work best, I would've thought    
ans3 <- ggplot(anscombe, aes(x = x2, y = y2))
ans3 <- ans3 + geom_point(aes(colour = "blue", size = 5))
ans3
```

The plot for `ans2` works as intended with the correct color aesthetics. However `ans3` does not work as intended. The `"blue"` color option does not register in geom_point(). Why does the aesthetic mapping work in `ans2` but not `ans3`

Also, take the following simple canonical examples:

```
# Aesthetic gets mapped correctly here
# explicitly mention `aes` in `geom_point`
b2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy))
b2 + geom_point(aes(col = fl, size = displ))

# Aesthetic does NOT get mapped correctly here
# don't mention `aes` in `geom_point`
b3 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy))
b3 + geom_point(col = fl, size = displ)
```

Why does `b2` work and `b3` throw an `object 'fl' not found` error?

I thought that `b3` is similar to `ans2` above which does work for `aes` mapping.

Any help appreciated

Comment: You need to re-read how aesthetic mappings work. If you put a color name/value **in** the `aes()` it will be scale transformed and won't be the color you expect if you don't use `scale_color/fill_identity()`. You need to put the static/identity mapping **outside** the `aes()` call to have them be interpreted properly. You just need to read more about ggplot2 vs toss random bits of code together.

Comment: Thanks @hrbrmstr. I was tossing random bits of code together to produce the example though :)! I haven't seen your explanation documented clearly but may have missed it. Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction

Comment: to add to hrbrmstr's comment - think of `aes` as *mapping* a variable from the data frame. Some familiar grouping variables include things like treatment groups, species, nationality, etc. If you have a column in your dataframe of that type, you can put that column name in the `aes()` declaration.